# Other Volumes issue

Tags: disk-utility, mojave

I have no idea what previous MacBook Pro owner did, but here is my disk:
[image: Other Volumes on storage]

I've got it with Mojava already and I think it's happened on OS update. Something like wrongly repaired of different file system type. Now I've got AFPS.

**diskutil apfs list**:

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 9EEBD262-1A13-4769-BE71-F470AC0F2735
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      499412676608 B (499.4 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   492989251584 B (493.0 GB) (98.7% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       6423425024 B (6.4 GB) (1.3% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 0DC53FB9-A4E9-4F73-B2CD-50B1C7032D5D
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       499412676608 B (499.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 542CAA9A-0C5D-4E15-9F67-82444DBCA0B6
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Mac OS (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         33422069760 B (33.4 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 F27CF301-8024-4040-B505-B2BF2B83A0A8
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         67284992 B (67.3 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 3F5C027A-5660-4CA0-90D3-7B77A15A0278
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         512462848 B (512.5 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 45752D3C-B9C4-4FE9-9D23-5B9126B02CAB
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /Volumes/VM
        Capacity Consumed:         1074536448 B (1.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

And here is another one:

**diskutil list**

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 9EEBD262-1A13-4769-BE71-F470AC0F2735
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      499412676608 B (499.4 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   493658509312 B (493.7 GB) (98.8% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       5754167296 B (5.8 GB) (1.2% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 0DC53FB9-A4E9-4F73-B2CD-50B1C7032D5D
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       499412676608 B (499.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 542CAA9A-0C5D-4E15-9F67-82444DBCA0B6
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Mac OS (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         34091319296 B (34.1 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 F27CF301-8024-4040-B505-B2BF2B83A0A8
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         67284992 B (67.3 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 3F5C027A-5660-4CA0-90D3-7B77A15A0278
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Recovery
    |   Capacity Consumed:         512462848 B (512.5 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 45752D3C-B9C4-4FE9-9D23-5B9126B02CAB
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /Volumes/VM
        Capacity Consumed:         1074536448 B (1.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

I've tried different tools and find information about huge amount of data that vas kipped and removed out of the disk. More than the disk size itself. Something about 700Gb out of 500Gb SSD.

I'll try to downgrade Mojave to High Sierra to change AFPS to something different and then wape out all the data. I'll share my experience if nobody will not stops me now)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I've made it. Just Erase my drive, remove Contrainer, change it to exFAT, change it to MacOS Extended and back to the AFPS. Add some splitting (have no idea what for and here it is - all my disk volume is here.

[image: Storage rescued]